# torch.cuda.is_available() returns different value for two projects*

Tags: python, pytorch, pycharm

I have two simple projects in the PyCharm; both of them start with the line:

```
import torch
is_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
```

Why does the first project return True, and the second False when both are running very similar environemt?

Comment: What do you mean by very similar? different environment variables being set could give different values here. For instance if the env var `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is set to 0, you will always get False.

Comment: Which vars? My workflow was nearly the same.

Comment: I have edited and added an example

Comment: Nearly the same is not "the same", differences in the environment probably explain differences in CUDA availability. Please include all relevant information in the question.

Comment: Not sure where to start. I have tried to force CUDA usage, but now I get ""Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled".

Comment: OK, resolved it by going into Conda env and unistalling/installing `torch` package.